# Adding Fields to an existing Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have another problem to solve here. Thinking in arrays sometimes could be very challenging. Here is what I am lined up with. This is what my data looks like: -

```
{
"_id": { "Firm": "ABC", "year": 2014 },
"Headings": [ 
    { 
        "costHead": "MNF", 
        "amount": 500000 
    },
    { 
        "costHead": "SLS",
        "amount": 25000
    }, 
    { 
        "costHead": "OVRHD",
        "amount": 100
    }
]
}
{
"_id": { "Firm": "CDF", "year": 2015 },
"Headings": [
     { 
        "costHead": "MNF",
        "amount": 15000 
     },
     { 
        "costHead": "SLS", 
        "amount": 100500 
     }, 
     { 
        "costHead": "MNTNC", 
        "amount": 7500 
     }
]
}
```

As you can see, I have a list that has a whole bunch of sub-documents.
Here is what I want to do .. I need to add more elements to this "Headings" list which should be : -

```
{
   "costHead": "FxdCost", 
   "amount": "$Headings.amount (for costhead MFC)  + $Headings.amount (for costhead OVRHD)"
}
```

I am unsure as to how to produce the above. Here are some challenges: -

1. I can addToSet the new subdocument I wish to add but the problem is addToSet can only be used in the group stage - which would be expensive (unless of course there is no other way).
2. Even if I use addToSet, I always have to use the $ operator to refer to elements that I read from my JSON file. Now the element I am trying to add here (costHead: FxdCost) is not present in my JSON file and hence I cannot use the $ operator.

Does anyone have any advice on how to go about this. This is after all basic ETL.

Comment: Your documents are not valid, can you please have a look at them, possibly formatting the JSON as you do?

Comment: Hi Chridam, I have updated them .. just two }} which were left out while trying to format them. The 2nd piece of highlighted code below , is what I want it to look like

Comment: Your documents are still invalid. There is no top level key for the object `{"Headings"...}`. Also, please use code formatting, not the quote formatting for objects.

Comment: sorry about that again .. I hate to be wasting anyone's time here finding syntax errors. I have corrected that .. double checked now.